# Circular list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

I have a list in example `li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
now I want slice of list exapmle:
`li[1:4]` will give  `[2,3,4]`

now I want the other part of list i.e  `[5,6,7,8,1]`
so how can I get it pythonically.

Answer (score 4):

Just add the first element to the end of the remaining elements from index 4 to the end

```
l1  = li[1:4]
l2 = li[4:] + [li[0]]

In [22]: li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

In [23]: l1  = li[1:4]

In [24]: l2 = li[4:]+ [li[0]]

In [25]: l1
Out[25]: [2, 3, 4]

In [26]: l2
Out[26]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

In two steps using `extend`:

```
l2 = li[4:]    
In [30]: l2.extend([li[0]])  
Out[31]: [5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (not the most efficient) way is to take the same list twice and slice from that:

```
def circ_slice(a, start, length):
    return (a * 2)[start:start+length]

a = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print circ_slice(a, 2, 4)  # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print circ_slice(a, 7, 4)  # [7, 8, 0, 1]
```

"tail + head" solutions require if statements if the start position is not known in advance.

Here's a more efficient version:

```
import itertools

def circ_slice(a, start, length):
    it = itertools.cycle(a)
    next(itertools.islice(it, start, start), None)
    return list(itertools.islice(it, length))
```

Comment: Nice `itertools` example ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
l1  = li[1:4]
l2 = li[4:]+ [li[0]]
```

On a side note:

You may check [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) which can be used to get the result in an efficient way.

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a
>   copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the
>   saved copy. Repeats indefinitely